# C# Textbox.Text is not formatting correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having an issue getting a windows forms text box (or at least the string that its text is comprised of) to format correctly. I am attempting to get something like:

```
Rating   Frequency
1        1
2        1
3        4
etc...
```

However, my code is spitting out:

```
Rating      Frequency1      12
13        1 etc..
```

It appears my newline characters are not working correctly, and I have tried carriage returns (\r) as well. Here is my code:

```
// set temp string to hold output
            string tempData;

            // fill temp string with number : inputs
            tempData = $"Rating\tFrequency" + "\n" +
                $"1\t\t {pollNumbers[0]}" + "\n" +
                $"2\t\t {pollNumbers[1]}" + "\n" +
                $"3\t\t {pollNumbers[2]}" + "\n" +
                $"4\t\t {pollNumbers[3]}" + "\n" +
                $"5\t\t {pollNumbers[4]}" + "\n" +
                $"6\t\t {pollNumbers[5]}" + "\n" +
                $"7\t\t {pollNumbers[6]}" + "\n" +
                $"8\t\t {pollNumbers[7]}" + "\n" +
                $"9\t\t {pollNumbers[8]}" + "\n" +
                $"10\t\t {pollNumbers[9]}";

            // assign output to displayTextBox
            displayTextBox.Text = tempData;
```

Comment: Have you set `Multiline` to `true`? Have you tried `Environment.Newline`?

Comment: @MarcGravell I resolved this by using Environment.NewLine in place of "\r" or "\n". Thank you, I hadn't thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

What Marc said in the comment.

Alternative approach is to use "right tool for the job" ;)

DataGridView

```
public class PollResult
{
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int Number{ get; set; }
}

var results = pollNumbers
    .Select((number, index) => new PollResult
    { 
        Rating = index, 
        Number = number 
    })
    .ToList();

dataGridView.DataSource = results;
```

You can configure datagridview's style to look as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I <3 fixed width fonts.

```
        displayTextBox.Multiline = true;
        displayTextBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25F);

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        int colWidth = 10;

        lines.Add("Rating".PadRight(colWidth, ' ') + "Frequency".PadLeft(colWidth, ' '));

        for (int i = 0; i < pollNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            lines.Add($"{i+1}".PadRight(colWidth, ' ') + $"{pollNumbers[i]}".PadLeft(colWidth, ' '));
        }

        // assign output to displayTextBox
        displayTextBox.Lines = lines.ToArray();
```